# Difference between returning each object or one arrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, arraycollection

```
public function getInvoiceItemsByType($type)
{
    return $this->invoiceItems->filter(function ($invoice) use ($type) {
        /** @var InvoiceItem $invoice */
        return $invoice->getType() == $type;
    }
    );
}

public function getInvoiceItemsByType($type) {
    foreach ($this->invoiceItems as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getType() == $type) {
            return $invoice;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

is there a difference between these two functions ? Someone told me that there is one but I can't manage to find what is it precisely and how one function instead of the other would affect my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that

```
return $this->invoiceItems->filter(function ($invoice) use ($type) {
    /** @var InvoiceItem $invoice */
    return $invoice->getType() == $type;
});
```

Will return **all** items which match or an empty ArrayCollection when nothing is found.

---

While

```
foreach ($this->invoiceItems as $invoice) {
    if ($invoice->getType() == $type) {
        return $invoice;
    }
}
return null;
```

Will only ever return **the first item** of the array that matches `$invoice->getType() == $type` or null if it does not exist at all.